# Do all ultimates charge at the same speed?

Tags: overwatch

Lately I have been playing a lot as Tracer and noticed my ultimate charges faster than other characters. Do all ultimates charge at the same speed, what exactly effects it?

Comment: it increases slowly with time, and when you hit an enemy player it increases rapidly

Comment: @JeremyAvalon aw man, I waisted like 3 minutes typing my answer, not realising there were already quite a few :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, the primary role of the hero, and is he fulfilling  it, is the main ultimate charge booster.

For instance, if you're a Mercy and stay at your spawn your Ultimate will charge quite slowly. if, on the other had you're healing someone who's taking alot of damage, your ultimate will charge **much** faster.

Also check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4lxem1/ultimate_charge_rate_of_all_heroes/) thread out. To summarise:

**Passive charge rate (from fastest to slowest)**

- 5% charge in approx 4 seconds (mech-less D.VA)
- 5% charge in approx 7.5 seconds (Symmetra)
- 5% charge in approx 8.5 seconds (Tracer)
- 5% charge in approx 9 seconds (Mei, Widowmaker, Mercy)
- 5% charge in approx 10 seconds (Roadhog, Reinhardt)
- 5% charge in approx 12 seconds(Genji, McCree, Hanzo, Junkrat, Torbjorn, D.VA, Reinhardt, Winston)
- 5% charge in approx 15 seconds (Pharah, Reaper, Soldier 76, Bastion,
  Zarya, Lucio, Zenyatta)

**And now for how much heroes charge for damaging enemies** (from highest to lowest):

- 60% charge for 200 damage (mech-less D.VA)
- 25% charge for 200 damage (Symmetra)
- 22% charge for 200 damage (Tracer) 20% charge for 200 damage (Mei, Widowmaker)
- 18% charge for 200 damage (Winston, Roadhog, Reinhardt)
- 16% charge for 200 damage (Genji, McCree, Hanzo, Junkrat, Torbjorn, D.VA)
- 14% charge for 200 damage (Pharah, Reaper, Soldier 76, Bastion, Zarya)
- 12% charge for 200 damage (Zenyatta)
- 10% charge for 200 damage (Lucio)